# Error in executing python file to configure WAS Admin Console properties

Tags: python, websphere

I am trying to configure WAS Admin Console properties via python file but getting following error:

```
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "ConfigureWASMain.py"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 49, in ?
  File "/opt/WebSphere7/64bit/optionalLibraries/jython/Lib/javaos.py", line 137, in __getitem__
  File "/opt/WebSphere7/64bit/optionalLibraries/jython/Lib/UserDict.py", line 14, in __getitem__
KeyError: BASE_DIR
```

Im my python file i have the follwoing code:

```
import os
import sys
from java.util import Hashtable
from java.util import Properties
from java.io import FileInputStream
sys.path.append(os.environ["BASE_DIR"]) //Line 49
```

Someone please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the environment variable `BASE_DIR` set. If you use bash, do

```
export BASE_DIR=/path/to/whatever
```

before you run the python code (in the same terminal window)

You should also assume sane defaults if `BASE_DIR` is not defined by user

```
sys.path.append(os.environ.get("BASE_DIR","/some/default/path"))
```

Comment: ya..i got it..in my shell script i forgt to use export BASE_DIR to home directory path. Thanks RedBaron